# how to get coefficient list from a polynomial with negative powers

Tags: polynomials, coefficients

Say a polynomial `x^2-x^(-2)`, I need to extract its coefficient.
I tried the command `CoefficientList[x^2-x^(-2)]`, but no result comes out.

[image]

I am confused why it happens. How can I get the desired result `{-1,0,0,0,1}`?

It should be an easy question, but I do not know the suitable command. Would you please give me some tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would it be OK for you to look separately for the list of coefficients with positive and that with negative powers? If yes, try this. Let us introduce a rule transforming, say, `x^-2` into `y^2`:

```
rule = Power[x, n_] /; n < 0 -> y^-n;
```

Here is your polynomial:

```
p = x^2 - x^(-2);
```

Now this:

```
CoefficientList[p /. rule, x] /. y -> 0
CoefficientList[p /. rule, y] /. x -> 0
(* {0, 0, 1}
   {0, 0, -1}   *)
```

gives us the answers separately for positive and negative powers.

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is ok to separate items with positive and negative powers. But I still wonder why there is no such a direct command to gain coefficients for both items with positive and negative  powers:)

Comment: It is a general situation. Mma has no all functions that one can wish. In this case, we may write our own functions and use when needed. Taking my idea as a basis you might like to construct such a function.

Answer (score 4):

Could find the min exponent, then make it an explicit polynomial.

```
laurentCoefficientList[lpol_, x_] := With[
  {min = Exponent[lpol, x, Min]}, CoefficientList[lpol/x^min, x]]

In[56]:= laurentCoefficientList[x^2 - x^(-2), x]

(* Out[56]= {-1, 0, 0, 0, 1} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your spelling (upper-case L):

```
CoefficientList[x^2 - x^(-2), x]
```

From the documentation:  "Terms that do not contain positive integer powers of a particular variable are included in the first element of the list for that variable."

Comment: It is a spelling mistake, and is trivial. The question has been updated.