# How to make a replacement rule matching exponents including 0 and 1

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

==============Edit for solution(s):

For anybody who does not need to worry about the structure of any coefficents and has non-negative powers this solution from @kirma works very well:

```
(Table[x^i y^j, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}] //     CoefficientRules[#, {x, y}] &) /. {{n_, m_} -> v_} :> v x y^(n + m) - CoefficientRules
```

If negative powers are included one can extend this using the asnwer here [how to get coefficient list from a polynomial with negative powers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186090/how-to-get-coefficient-list-from-a-polynomial-with-negative-powers)

For my specific problem I have found a solution, if we call my expression expr:

```
(expr/.Derivative[tdiv1_,xdiv1_,ydiv1_,zdiv1_][A][t, x, y, z]*Derivative[tdiv2_,xdiv2_,ydiv2_,zdiv2_][B][t, x, y, z]/; xdiv1 + xdiv2 > 0 -> (-1)^(tdiv2+xdiv2+ydiv2+zdiv2-1) Inactivate[D[ Coefficient[expr,Derivative[tdiv1,xdiv1,ydiv1,zdiv1][A][t, x, y, z]*Derivative[tdiv2,xdiv2,ydiv2,zdiv2][B][t, x, y, z]]Derivative[tdiv1,xdiv1+xdiv2-1,ydiv1+ydiv2,zdiv1+zdiv2][A][t, x, y, z],{t,tdiv2}]*Derivative[0,1,0,0][B][t, x, y, z]/Coefficient[expr,Derivative[tdiv1,xdiv1,ydiv1,zdiv1][A][t, x, y, z]*Derivative[tdiv2,xdiv2,ydiv2,zdiv2][B][t, x, y, z]]])//Activate
```

note: without inactivating the `Coefficient` calls one gets a 0/0 error

I have not yet tested but I believe this can be made into a general rule for any expression by delaying the definition of the rule like so:

```
rule[expr_]:=Derivative[tdiv1_,xdiv1_,ydiv1_,zdiv1_][A][t, x, y, z]*Derivative[tdiv2_,xdiv2_,ydiv2_,zdiv2_][B][t, x, y, z]/; xdiv1 + xdiv2 > 0 -> (-1)^(tdiv2+xdiv2+ydiv2+zdiv2-1) Inactivate[D[ Coefficient[expr,Derivative[tdiv1,xdiv1,ydiv1,zdiv1][A][t, x, y, z]*Derivative[tdiv2,xdiv2,ydiv2,zdiv2][B][t, x, y, z]]Derivative[tdiv1,xdiv1+xdiv2-1,ydiv1+ydiv2,zdiv1+zdiv2][A][t, x, y, z],{t,tdiv2}]*Derivative[0,1,0,0][B][t, x, y, z]/Coefficient[expr,Derivative[tdiv1,xdiv1,ydiv1,zdiv1][A][t, x, y, z]*Derivative[tdiv2,xdiv2,ydiv2,zdiv2][B][t, x, y, z]]])
```

then:

```
expr/.rule[expr]
```

should work I believe

Another option, using `CoefficientList`:

```
list= CoefficientList[expr/.a[t]^n_ /; n < 0 -> inva[t] (*and similar transformations for other powers that are negative*),{a[t],b[t](*,..*),inva[t](*,..*)}
```

Followed by:

```
Activate[Sum[list[[aindex, bindex, invaindex]]/.Derivative[tdivscal_, xdivscal_, ydivscal_, zdivscal_][A][t, x, y, z]*Derivative[tdivvec_, xdivvec_, ydivvec_, zdivvec_][B][t, x, y, z] /; xdivscal + xdivvec > 0 -> (-1)^(tdivvec + xdivvec + ydivvec + zdivvec - 1)*Inactivate[D[a[t]^(aindex - invaindex)*b[t]^(bindex - 1)(* times any other factors *)*Derivative[tdivscal, xdivscal + xdivvec - 1, ydivscal + ydivvec, zdivscal + zdivvec][A][t, x, y, z], {t, tdivvec}]]*Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][B], {aindex, 1, Length[list]}, {bindex, 1,Length[list[[aindex]]]}, {invaindex, 1, Length[list[[aindex, bindex]]]}(*, any other indices necessary*)]]
```

End of Edit

==============

I am having some trouble writing a repalcement rule with the properties I want.

A simple example which demonstates my issue is the replacement rule:

```
Table[x^i y^j, {i,0,3}, {j,0,3}]/.x^n_ y^m_ -> x y^(n+m)
```

This only works, as I would want it to, for i and j>1 i.e. the pattern is not matched by 1, x, y, x^n, y^m , x^n y or x y^m. Is there a simple modification that will recognize `1` as `x^0 y^0`, `x` as `x^1 y^0` etc.?

My actual use case is a lot more complicated and so writing out the "exceptional" cases directly is impractical

A partial solution, as given by @kglr below:

```
Table[x^i y^j, {i,0,3}, {j,0,3}]/.x^n_. y^m_. -> x y^(n+m)
```

extends the replacement to work for i and j > 0 but it still does not match x as x y^0, and setting the default values to 0 like so:

```
Table[x^i y^j, {i,0,3}, {j,0,3}]/.x^n_:0 y^m_:0 -> x y^(n+m)
```

works as the original with no defaults

A solution that may work for others from @kirma

```
Table[Inactivate[x^i y^j, Power], {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}] /.   Inactive[Power][x, n_] Inactive[Power][y, m_] :> x y^(n + m)
```

however in my case the expression I am replacing comes after a long calculation and contains many terms, so inactivating powers in the left hand side is not a viable solution.

edit: as it seems to be causing some issues. My specific problem is that I have a long expression with many terms of the form:

```
a[t] b[t] Derivative[tdiv1,xdiv1,ydiv1,zdiv1][A][t, x, y, z]*Derivative[tdiv2,xdiv2,ydiv2,zdiv2][B][t, x, y, z]
```

where `a[t]` and `b[t]` (say a, b, c ,d) can one of several options, as can `A` and `B`. I want to end up (e.g.) with

```
   (-1)^(tdiv2+xdiv2+ydiv2+zdiv2-1) D[a[t] b[t] Derivative[tdiv1,xdiv1+xdiv2-1,ydiv1+ydiv2,zdiv1+zdiv2][A][t, x, y, z],{t,tdiv2}]*Derivative[0,1,0,0][B][t, x, y, z]
```

my current attempt is

```
a[t]^na_ b[t]^nb_ c[t]^nc_ d[t]^nd_ Derivative[tdiv1_,xdiv1_,ydiv1_,zdiv1_][A][t, x, y, z]*Derivative[tdiv2_,xdiv2_,ydiv2_,zdiv2_][B][t, x, y, z]/; xdiv1 + xdiv2 > 0 -> (-1)^(tdiv2+xdiv2+ydiv2+zdiv2-1) Inactivate[D[a[t]^na b[t]^nb c[t]^nc d[t]^nd Derivative[tdiv1,xdiv1+xdiv2-1,ydiv1+ydiv2,zdiv1+zdiv2][A][t, x, y, z],{t,tdiv2}]]*Derivative[0,1,0,0][B][t, x, y, z]
```

Comment: There is a typo: `x^_n` should be `x^n`!

Comment: try `Table[x^i y^j, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}] /.   x^n_. y^m_. :>  x y^(n + m)`?

Comment: The typo was only in the post, not the notebook. I have corrected it.

@kglr your suggestion makes it work for i and j > 0 but the 0 case still does not work

Comment: see also [Tutorial  >>Optional And Default Arguments](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionalAndDefaultArguments.html)

Comment: @kglr As I said above, and have added to the question, this seems to help only with the i and/or j =1 cases only

Comment: `Inactivate` the `Power` operator (preventing it from evaluating on the spot) and rewrite inactivated terms: `Table[Inactivate[x^i y^j, Power], {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}] /. 
 Inactive[Power][x, n_] Inactive[Power][y, m_] :> x y^(n + m)`

Comment: @kirma this works very well for the example thank you. However this does not work for my actual use case. The powers in the expression I am replacing cannot be inactivated

Comment: can you post the desired result for your example?

Comment: @kglr the desired result is found exactly using the suggestion of @kirma `Table[Inactivate[x^i y^j, Power], {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}] /.   Inactive[Power][x, n_] Inactive[Power][y, m_] :> x y^(n + m) ` 

however my expression contains hundreds of terms and must be evaluated long before I get to the point I need to make these replacements. So I need something with the same behaviour which works without the `Inactivate` in the table

Comment: how about `x (Table[x^i y^j, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}] /. x -> y)`?

Comment: @kglr this won't work for i=j=0. Also it is too focussed on how the table looks and the particular replacement. My replacement rule and expression are a lot more complicated, the example only captures the issue I haven't managed to solve, not the full problem

Comment: You can do also something like `(Table[x^i y^j, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}] // 
   CoefficientRules[#, {x, y}] &) /. {{n_, m_} -> v_} :> v x y^(n + m)` - `CoefficientRules` being the central point here. This way you can consistently find zeroth and first powers of specific variables.

Comment: @kirma thanks, I will look up CoefficientRules and see if it solves my problem

Comment: Even further, if your results are sums of multiple polynomials, you can do something like this (adapted to this specific case, where it isn't relevant): `(Table[x^i y^j, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}] // CoefficientRules[#, {x, y}] &) /. ({n_, m_} -> v_) :> v x y^(n + m) // Total[#, {3}] &`

Comment: @kirma my two main problems with implementing this solution is that `v` will be a sum of quadratic things which I will need to split up (I think I can solve this myself, though `CoefficientList` might actually be more useful for that). The other is that I sometimes have negative powers of `x` and `y`. I may need to introduce some `invx` and `invy` as suggested here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186090/how-to-get-coefficient-list-from-a-polynomial-with-negative-powers

Comment: So your actual problem has nothing to do with exponents?

Comment: @mmeent well as I approached my problem it did have a lot to do with exponents. The "current attempt" at the bottom of the question fails because mathematica recognises `A[t,x,y,z]` as `Derivative[0,0,0,0][A][t, x, y, z]` but not `1` as `a^0`. I think I have a solution now though, which I am typing up